# jsf, primefaces, pass data from dialog to other bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi

i need pass value from opened dialog to 'parent' bean,

open new dialog from formBean

```
 @Named(value = FormBean.NAME)
 @SessionScoped //or @ViewScoped from omnifaces
 public class FormBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {
 public static final String NAME = "formBean";
 @Getter @Setter private boolean updateRequest = false;
 @Getter @Setter private String value;
  // in some method open dialog
  AbstractDialogBean.openDialog(type.getUrl());

  public void fillView(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if(!getFacesContext().isPostback()) {
      initialRequest();
    } else {
      postBackRequest();
    }
  }

 private void postBackRequest() {
  Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ":" value);
  if(updateRequest) {
   Ajax.updateAl();
  }
 }

}
```

in AbstractDialogBean

```
  public static void openDialog(String dialogFilePath) {
    Map<String, Object> opt = new HashMap() {{
      put("modal", true);
      put("resizable", false);
    }};
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(dialogFilePath, opt, null);
  }
```

one of dialogs files

```
<ui:composition template="/page.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:cp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
                xmlns:jl="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/jsflive"
                xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
  <ui:define name="title">#{locationBean.getTitle()}</ui:define>
  <ui:define name="pageContent">
    <h:form id="as">
      <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel id="dataLabel" value="data"/>
        <p:inputText id="data" value="#{locationBean.value}"/>
      </p:panelGrid>
      <p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:commandButton id="ok" value="ok" actionListener="#{locationBean.actionListener}"/>
        <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="cancel" actionListener="#{locationBean.actionListener}"/>
      </p:toolbarGroup>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

after submit ok button, i need to pass data value into formBean from locationBean;
but postBackRequest() in formBean executed before actionListener() in locationBean, and value is null in formBean

LocationBean code;

```
@Named(value = LocationBean.NAME)
@RequestScoped
public class LocationBean extends AbstractDialogBean implements Serializable {
  public static final String NAME = "locationBean";
  @Getter private FormBean formBean;
  @Getter @Setter private String value;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    formBean = getFacesContext().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(getFacesContext(), "#{" + FormBean.NAME + "}", FormBean.class);
  }

  public void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
   if (event.getComponent().getId().equals("ok")) {
     formBean.setValue(value);  //try to pass entered value into mainBean
     formBean.setUpdateRequest(true);
   }
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(event.getSource());
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: why dont you inject the formbean in the locationbean?

Comment: I tried, the same result, after press 'ok' button at first called fillView(postBackRequest) in formBean after that actionListener in locationBean